# Javascript variable being overwriiten after query execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using mysql database with Nodejs. I am running a query like this:

```
     rows = await pool.query(`Select partID,stageID,locationID,QuantityAfter, QuantityChange, rowDeleted from InventoryTransactions
                where partID = ${item.partID} and stageID = ${item.stageID} and locationID = ${item.locationID} and orderID = ${orderID}
                order by transactionID desc`)




if(rows[0].rowDeleted != 1){  //This means that the quantity in the inventory table and inv trans table is not the same
                console.log(`=====================================`)
                console.log(Number(rows[0].QuantityChange))
                console.log(Number(rows[0].QuantityChange))
                console.log(Number(rows[0].QuantityChange))


                await pool.query(`Insert into inventorytransactions(OrderID,PartID,LocationID,StageID,QuantityBefore,QuantityChange,QuantityAfter,ITTTimeStamp,rowDeleted,id) 
                 Values(${orderID},${rows[0].partID},${rows[0].locationID},${rows[0].stageID},${parseInt(rows[0].QuantityAfter)},${-parseInt(rows[0].QuantityChange)},${parseInt(rows[0].QuantityAfter)-parseInt(rows[0].QuantityChange)},'${(new Date ((new Date((new Date(new Date())).toISOString() )).getTime() - ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60000))).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')}',true,${id})`)

                 console.log(Number(rows[0].QuantityChange))
                 console.log(Number(rows[0].QuantityChange))
                 console.log(Number(rows[0].QuantityChange))
                console.log(`Update inventory set Quantity = quantity - ${Number(rows[0].QuantityChange)} where partID =${rows[0].partID} and stageID = ${rows[0].stageID} and locationID = ${rows[0].locationID}`)

                await pool.query(`Update inventory set Quantity = quantity - ${Number(rows[0].QuantityChange)} where partID =${rows[0].partID} and stageID = ${rows[0].stageID} and locationID = ${rows[0].locationID} `)

                console.log(`=====================================`)
            }
```

The reason I have so many `console.log` is because I have encountered a very weird bug. All of the values of `rows[0].QuantityChange)` should be the same.

But my console shows:

```
====================================
4
4
4
425
NaN
NaN
NaN
Update inventory set Quantity = quantity - NaN where partID =12462 and stageID = 1 and locationID = 1
{ Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'
```

I know 425 is the value of `${id}` variable which can be found at the end of the insert sql statement. Which makes no sense to me. What makes even less sense is how are the the bottom values are undefined or NAN

Comment: The `425` likely comes from some other code that is running during your `await pool.query()` statement.  `await` blocks the execution of the local function, but it does not block the event queue so other events can run while an `await ...` is waiting for completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `425` likely comes from some other code that is running during your `await pool.query()` statement (not from anything in the code you show us).  `await` blocks the execution of the local function, but it does not block the event queue so other events can run while an `await ...` is waiting for completion.

Then, you don't show where `rows` is defined, but it seems possible that it's getting overwritten by some other code that is running during the `await`.  If you show us a lot more context around this code including where `rows` is defined, we could advise and explain in more detail.

Comment: Yeah this makes a lot of sense to me know. I have a few async code firing at the same time most of which uses the row variable. This is why the variable only changed after the await. You have answered so many of my questions. Thank you

Comment: @jedu - When doing any asynchronous programming, for your processing within the function it's best to use local variables only that are not shared with any other code.  This is also just a generally good programming guidelines too for all code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but, in this part

```
'${(new Date ((new Date((new Date(new Date())).toISOString() )).getTime() - ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60000))).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')}'
```

Exist an incorrect use of single quotes, which can be altering the result of the consult. You should scape inner single quotes, or use Double quotes for wrapping the complete instruction.

```
"${(new Date ((new Date((new Date(new Date())).toISOString() )).getTime() - ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60000))).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')}"
```

Comment: No I am pretty sure this is a correct use of single quotes. I have used this successfully 100s of time in my project. The problem was apparently becuase of leaked variable cause I used the same variable `rows` in my other functions. I added `let` infront of the variable and everything is working fine

Comment: I am however still curious about why the variable was leaking only after the `await`. Hopefully someone will explain soon